# Issue configuring gradlew tool inorder to build an .aab (Android App Bundle) from cordova

Tags: android, cordova, bundle, gradlew

After firering:

> .\gradlew.bat bundle --info

on windows i got these error message:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'
> Unable to determine Android SDK directory.

But the SDK directory is perfectly added in my Windows PATH

> ANDROID_SDK_HOME
> C:\Users\SomeUser.android
>
> PATH:
> C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin

Can anyone help what went wrong?
Is there a gradle configuration file?

Answer (score 2):

For me, this brought the solution.

I added **ANDROID_HOME** to my system variables:

Example:

> set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\
>
> set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

Comment: No. If you use "set PATH" option in a terminal (cmd) you do not need to restart!

Comment: I was successful with 
ANDROID_HOME = path to SDK, 
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = path to SDK,
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271